# How can I pass array to LLVM IR Function arguments and get value by index

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, llvm

I want to pass an array to LLVM IR Function, and get value by index. The code as follows, but it dont't work.

```
  Function *FooF =
      Function::Create(FunctionType::get(Type::getInt32Ty(Context), {ArrayType::getInt32PtrTy(Context), Type::getInt32Ty(Context)}, false),
                       Function::ExternalLinkage, "foo", M);
  // Add a basic block to the FooF function.
  BasicBlock *BB = BasicBlock::Create(Context, "EntryBlock", FooF);
  IRBuilder<> builder(BB);
  // Get pointer to array
  Value *arg1 = FooF->arg_begin();
  // Get index
  Value *index = arg1+1;
  // Get first_element
  Value *first_element = builder.CreateExtractElement(arg1, index);
  builder.CreateRet(first_element);

  // Now we create the JIT.
  ExecutionEngine* EE = EngineBuilder(std::move(Owner)).create();
  using FunctionPtr = int(*)(int32_t *, int);
  FunctionPtr func = reinterpret_cast<FunctionPtr>(EE->getFunctionAddress("foo")) ;
  int32_t array[3] = {1,2,3};
  int first = func(array, 0);

}
```

Comment: The function `FooF` expects a 3 element array by value, however, when you do `func(array, 0)` you're passing in fact a pointer to the array. C/C++ consturcts do not match 1-to-1 to LLVM-IR. You have to take into account the language, the calling-convention and the ABI. Some advice moving forward: you can write some C/C++ code that simulates the code you want to generate in LLVM-IR, then you can lower it to LLVM-IR and see how the high level constructs map to the IR.

Comment: Another solution is to use a raw pointer point to this array, but I have no idea how to get value by `ptr+i ` in IR builder